# PHPExcel reading .csv file with Hebrew content is Not Working Properly

Tags: php, csv, yii2, phpexcel

I tried to read a .csv file using the PHPExcel library but it is giving me question marks instead of the Hebrew text.

The problem only occur when I tried to upload .csv files created from Windows Operating System. I tried the same for MacOS and Linux and the data seems to be fine. How can I solve the encoding issue from windows

```
    public function actionUpload()
    {
            $params = $_FILES['uploadFile'];
            if($params)
            {
                $data = array();
                $model = new UploadForm();
                $model->uploadFile = $_FILES['uploadFile'];
                $file =  UploadedFile::getInstanceByname('uploadFile');
                $inputFileName = $model->getpath($file,$data);
                //  Read your Excel workbook
                try
                {
                    $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName['link']);
                    $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
                    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName['link']);
                }
                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName['link'],PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
                }
    
                //  Get worksheet dimensions
                $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
                $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
                $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
                $fileData = array();
                //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
                for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
                { 
                    //  Read a row of data into an array
                    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                                    NULL,
                                                    TRUE,
                                                    FALSE);
                    array_push($fileData,$rowData[0]);
                    //  Insert row data array into your database of choice here
                }
                return $fileData;
            }
            
   }
```

The output array has "???? ???" in places where Hebrew text was present when .csv files created from Windows was uploaded.

Comment: So where are you telling PHPExcel the charset of the file that it's reading?

Comment: `$objReader->setInputEncoding(<encoding for the CSV file>);` before the `load()`... otherwise PHPExcel assumes that the file is UTF-8

Comment: i tried above method but it didn't work

Comment: So what character encoding did you set?

Comment: tried both ISO-8859-1 and  UTF-8

Comment: If it's hebrew, then it's far more likely to be `Windows-1255` or `ISO 8859-8` than `ISO-8859-1`; and if it was `UTF-8` then PHPExcel would have been able to read it correctly without even needing to set the encoding

Comment: when  i used ISO 8859-8  got the message Wrong charset, conversion from `ISO 8859-8' to `UTF-8' is not allowed and on passing Windows-1255  the hebrew text is  still  showing '??????'

Comment: I can't guess for you, all I can do is offer suggestions as to what it might be (alternatives are `UTF-16LE` and `UTF-16BE`).... but ask whoever created it